# Achieving white opacity effect in html/css

Tags: html, css, opacity

is there a way to achieve this effect in a cross-browser compatible way without having to prepare separated images?

Basically the frame on which text lays has a white overlay of 50% opacity.. I would like a solution that doesn't involve creating any other image in addition to the background but I don't know if it's possible!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Styling visited images cross browser way / cross browser opacity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438671/css-styling-visited-images-cross-browser-way-cross-browser-opacity)

Comment: See the dupe. You'll have to put the black text into a separate DIV though

Comment: but note that filters for IE6 are really resource suckers (which a IE6 Workstation probably hasn't to much to spare from).

Comment: Using opacity I'm able to change the alpha of the background white DIV but how can I keep the text black? I placed it in a DIV inside the one with the background but it inherits opacity also if I override it through CSS

Comment: The CSS3 opacity rule will cascade to include your text; but the RGBA background-color in Bobby Jack's answer will not, giving you a 50% bgnd opacity and full opacity text.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Try RGBA, e.g.

```
div { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
```

As always, this won't work in every single browser ever written.

Comment: works but it's not compatible with IE, so I had to use a background image of 1 pixel with 50% alpha. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You may also want to declare a fallback color first like so: 

`color: #ffffff; /*fallback color*/
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);`

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use `rgba` due to browser support, and you don't want to include a semi-transparent white PNG, you will have to create two positioned elements. One for the white box, with opacity, and one for the overlaid text, solid.

```css
body { background: red; }

.box { position: relative; z-index: 1; }
.box .back {
    position: absolute; z-index: 1;
    top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: white; opacity: 0.75;
}
.box .text { position: relative; z-index: 2; }

body.browser-ie8 .box .back { filter: alpha(opacity=75); }
```

```html
<!--[if lt IE 9]><body class="browser-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!--><body><!--<![endif]-->
    <div class="box">
        <div class="back"></div>
        <div class="text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet blah blah boogley woogley oo.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```