# Transparent white background

Tags: html, css, web

Hi I want to have a white transparent background in a part of my body tag but I have tried some CSS yet its  still not working. its not even filling a white background.

**Here is my HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Guitar Corner</title>

        <link href="C:/Users/Jhan Jericho/Desktop/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

         <script src="C:/Users/Jhan Jericho/Desktop/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></script>
         <script src="C:/Users/Jhan Jericho/Desktop/bootstrap/jquery-1.7.1.intellisense.js"></script>
         <script src="C:/Users/Jhan Jericho/Desktop/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;">
                    <img src="bg2.jpg" alt="logo"/>
                </div>
                <div class="center-block">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-image:url('guitar.png');  background-size: 1200px 350px; background-repeat:no-repeat; shadow: 10px 0px 20px;"> 
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="GC.png" style="-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class=".col-xs-12 .col-md-8"><i>
                                <font face="Bebas Neue" color="white" size="150"><br />
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"We are attached by strings."
                                        &nbsp;</i>
                                </font>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="bodycolor">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="bartonav"><font color="white">
                        <h1>HOME</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bodycolor">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <br />
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">PROFILE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.bodycolor
{
 background-color: white;
}
```

I have edited and included my whole code here.

Comment: Do you want it transparent or white?

Comment: a white transparent background.

Comment: Do you mean semi-transparent?

Comment: Transparent means see-through, white is a color. If it is see-through it doesn't HAVE a color. So would you like a white background, or a transparent background?

Comment: Yes Curt a semi transparent.

Comment: Your HTML has an unclosed deprecated font tag.. also, if your block elements are floated be sure to clear them so your wrapper will receive the full height.. if you show your whole code, it'll be much easier to help you

Comment: I have tried this one but its not working for me, I want something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969380/achieving-white-opacity-effect-in-html-css

Answer (score 1):

To make a semi-transparent background, use rgba (to add an alpha value to the background color)

```
#idName
{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

The 0.5 at the end is the alpha channel, with 0 being transparent and 1 being Opaque.

Here is a JSFiddle showing transparency: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFnQt/)

Comment: Typo, meant to be idName. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: I want something like this, I have tried this and its not working for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969380/achieving-white-opacity-effect-in-html-css

Comment: `background-color` would be preferable to `background` I think?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="bodycolor">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="bartonav"><font color="white">
                        <h1>HOME</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="transparent">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <br />
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">PROFILE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
CSS
    .bodycolor
    {
     background-color: #FFF; /*general background color*/
    }
    .transparent
    {
     background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    }
```

Something like this ? Be careful , you're using the same class twice, the two parts will have the same background

Comment: I want the whole div of "body class" will have a white semi transparent background.

Comment: Does your code have been created by a WYSIWYG Editor ? Now you get a full white background instead of a transparent one ?                "<div id="bodycolor">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="bartonav"><font color="white">
                        <h1>HOME</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bodycolor">"

Comment: "<div id="bodycolor">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="bartonav"><font color="white">
                        <h1>HOME</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bodycolor">" You should create 2 different classes, because one will be transparent, and the second one will probably be white, because its reference for transparency will be a kind of white background